# How can I send a custom response from a firebase cloud function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I've written a firebase cloud function and everything works as expected, however when trying to read the response from the client side, the data I've returned from the cloud function isn't included in the response.

Here's my cloud function:

```
exports.employeeExists = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return response.status(500).json({
    data: {
      type: constants.REQUEST_ERROR,
      error: 'ERROR MESSAGE'
    }
  });
});
```

Here's my client-side request:

```
fetch('cloud function url', options)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

The output I get on the client-side log is the response with the correct status code that I've set (500), however the data that I send with the response isn't present.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: fetch() returns a Promise containing a Response object. The Promise can become either fulfilled or rejected. 500 is rejection Rejection and jumps to the catch(). Can you see what you've get in catch()?

Comment: I've tried with 2xx status codes as well and my response data would still be incorrect. I've found a fix though. Instead of using fetch() I used axios.post() and the response data I receive through axios contains all the data I am expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some struggling I decided to use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) instead of the built in fetch() function and now I am able to retrieve the response data I'm expecting just fine.